# PHP - Sending the current output buffer

Tags: php, irc

I'm making a PHP IRC Bot, and it works great.

What I want to do though, is to have a live debugging option, which means I need to see the commands sent from an operator to the bot live. The problem is, as long as the bot's running, no output is being sent, even if I `echo`, `printf`, or `var_dump`.

So my question is, how can I force PHP to send the current output buffer without waiting for the logic to finish (because theoretically, it won't finish ever :P)

EDIT:
`flush()` or `ob_flush()` doesn't seem to work, see this simple example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ks7zEy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [flush();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. I tried a simpler version with sleep(2);

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [ob_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. I tried a simpler version with `sleep(2);`

Comment: Did you call ob_start() in the beginning?

Comment: Indeed I have. I'm beginning to think that PHP's not the problem, because even after setting `output_buffering=Off` in php.ini, I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this at the top of your page:

```
while( ob_get_level() > 0 ) {
    @ob_end_flush();
}
@ob_implicit_flush();
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. I tried a simpler version with sleep(2);